# Receive Mouse Click from a seperate Running process

Tags: .net, process

Essentially what I'm trying to do is open a separate process and then receive mouse click events from that process, specifically the coordinates of the mouse click within that separate running process.

I've been up and down the Windows API (`SendMessage`, `mouse_event`) as well as the `System.Windows.Automation` stuff and I have found great information on sending events to separate running processes but nothing about receiving (other than the `StandardOutput`, which I don't think it's what I want here (I couldn't get it to work)).

I'm working in C# so that is preferable if you're going to post some code but I can do any language if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to look for 'Global Hooks'.

I found this helpful; but I wasn't interested in the mouse side of things.  Still, it claims to work :)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx

Comment: I saw this before I posted, spent some time trying to get this working within a specificapplication and not just the entire screen but I had no luck, have you been able to accomplish something similar?